# $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \ln(\bar{x})$ vs. $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \ln(x_i)$

Tags: inequality, summation

For a set $x = \{x_1, ..., x_n\}$, I need to show that

$$\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \ln(\bar{x}) \leq \sum_{i=1}^n x_i \ln(x_i),$$

where $\bar{x} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i$ is the arithmetic mean.

Intuitively, this makes sense. But how do you prove/show it formally?

Comment: *Intuitively, this makes sense.* $\leadsto$ why does it make sense? Maybe you can use this intuition to get a proof (?).

Answer (score 1):

*I am assuming that $x_i\geq 0$ for all $i$, with the convention that $0\log 0=0$, so that the question is well-defined.*

Consider the function $f\colon x\in[0,\infty) \mapsto x\ln x$. You can check it is convex.
Then, apply Jensen's inequality to the sum
$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \ln x_i = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n f(x_i)
$$
to get
$$
f\!\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nx_i \right) \leq \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n f(x_i)
$$